# uWSGI can not be installed on EC2(AWS) (Python3.10)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, wsgi

## Background

I am building web application with Flask/nginx on EC2 server(AWS, Amazon Linux 2). uWSGI is essential as an application server between nginx and Flask-based python programs. However, I can not install uWSGI with pip3.10. I can not find hints on the net, so I post this question.

## Environment

- Python (v3.10.10)
- 'sudo yum update' is done before installation.
- 'pip' is up-to-date.
- 'wheel' is installed.
- 'python3-devel' is already installed.

## When I tries to install uWSGI

```
Collecting uwsgi 
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.21.tar.gz (808KB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... \|/ l-error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

x python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
    [355 lines of output]
    /home/ec2-user/hoge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warning.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
    /home/ec2-user/hoge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
    !!
      **************************************************************
      Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
      Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/build or other standards-based tools.
      See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-depricated.html for details
      **************************************************************
    !!

    *****
    continues error output ....
    *****

    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a busprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for uwsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

## What I did when I received this error

I checked if "Development Tools" is installed by typing this command:

```
> sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn-core
amzn2extra-docker 
amzn2extra-epel
amzn2extra-kernel-5.10
amzn2extra-nginx1
epel/x86_64/metalink
epel-debuginfo/x86_64/metalink
epel-source/x86_64/metalink
epel-testing/x86_64/metalink
epel-testing
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64/metalink
epel-testing-debuginfo
epel-testing-source/x86_64/metalink
epel-testing-source
snapd-amzn2
(1/5): epel-testing/x86_64/updateinfo
(2/5): epel-testing/x86_64/primary_db
(3/5): epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64/primary_db
(4/5): epel-testing-source/x86_64/updateinfo
(5/5): epel-testing-source/x86_64/primary_db

244 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Maybe run: yum group mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update.
```

"Development Tools" seems not be installed. Any web pages describing how to install "Development Tools" tell me 'yum groupinstall "Development Tools"' is essential. But in my case, it seems that this command does not work.

## But when I checked the installed modules list

In previous section "Development Tools" is already installed.

```
> yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
244 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

Available Environment Groups:
  Cinnamon Desktop
  MATE Desktop
Installed Groupd:
  Development Tools <-- *** already exists ! ***
Available groups:
  AWS Tools
  ... more packages..
```

## Whatelse should I do ?

I tried to install uwsgi package into my python environment but the installation stops with error. I do not know what I should do to make the installation of uwsgi success. Please give me advise or comments. Thank you for reading my question !